# Calculating Daily Scaled Travel Distance for UTM Animal Movement Data in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, distance, utm

I am trying to calculate the daily distance travelled by each individual in my dataset. I have collected tracking data in UTM format, where each individual was tracked once per day. I've subset the data already in the following way as I have been doing other analyses with it:

```
iguana.data <- read.csv(file='iguanas1-22.csv')
iguana.data
names(iguana.data)
summary(iguana.data)

#my data is in this format before subsetting
animal            datetime      x       y        species country UTMzone
1    IG001 2019-03-19 14:45:00 291671 1977162 Cyclura collei Jamaica     18N
2    IG001 2019-03-20 14:10:00 291670 1977157 Cyclura collei Jamaica     18N
3    IG001 2019-03-21 11:23:00 291670 1977157 Cyclura collei Jamaica     18N
4    IG001 2019-03-22 12:04:00 291670 1977157 Cyclura collei Jamaica     18N
5    IG001 2019-03-23 12:54:00 291671 1977162 Cyclura collei Jamaica     18N

animal.clean <- iguana.data %>%
  dplyr::select(animal, x, y, datetime)

head(animal.clean)
tail(animal.clean,10)

>
animal      x       y            datetime
1  IG001 291671 1977162 2019-03-19 14:45:00
2  IG001 291670 1977157 2019-03-20 14:10:00
3  IG001 291670 1977157 2019-03-21 11:23:00
4  IG001 291670 1977157 2019-03-22 12:04:00
5  IG001 291671 1977162 2019-03-23 12:54:00
6  IG001 291671 1977162 2019-03-24 12:40:00

animal      x       y            datetime
1602 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-05 10:01:00
1603 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-06 09:45:00
1604 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-07 10:17:00
1605 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-08 08:21:00
1606 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-09 08:03:00
1607 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-10 10:34:00
1608 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-11 11:00:00
1609 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-12 10:32:00
1610 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-13 09:21:00
1611 IG0022 291693 1977345 2019-07-14 09:45:00

animal.clean$datetime <- as.POSIXct(animal.clean$datetime,
                                    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
                                    tz = "America/Jamaica")
```

What is the most straightforward way to measure the daily scaled travel distance between all location fixes for each individual in R? All the points are in the correct order, but there are some dates missing as it is radio telemetry data, therefore it was not possible to track every single day. I have found similar questions that tackle this topic but none that deal with my type of data format specifically.

Advice on the code to perform this would be much appreciated, as I am fairly new to R.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the rgeos package and the gDistance function to calculate the distance between given points.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me any advice on how I would implement this in my code? I have tried to use the gDistance function but it isn't working for me.

Comment: On second thought, `sf` is a better way to go than `rgeos`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with a reproducible example using the `sf` package. Be sure to have a look at the example dataset (`?meuse`) and note I grouped the point attributes by flooding frequency class (ffreq). You could potentially do something similar with animal ID.

```
#load sf package
library(sf)
data('meuse', package = "sp")

#mconvert to a spatial object
ms <- st_as_sf(
  meuse, 
  coords = c('x', 'y'),
  crs = "+init=epsg:28992"
)

class(ms)

#plot the data by flood frequency class
plot(ms["ffreq"])

#calculate pairwise distance 
ms %>%
  group_by(ffreq) %>%
  mutate(
    lead = geometry[row_number() + 1],
    dist = st_distance(geometry, lead, by_element = T),
  )
```

Have a look at the dist attribute in the attribute table for the distance between successive points (in successive rows).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much Tim. As you suggested, I grouped the point attributes by animal id and it worked perfectly. I presume the values in the dist attributes are in metres by default?

Comment: Glad it worked. I believe the distance units should be in the same units of the projection. I would do a test on the subset of the data and verify in a GIS just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved same results using the function step_lengths from the package {amt}. Here you have to create a track first using the function make_track. Afterwards you can use the step_lengths function. The results are equal in my case.